# Methods of finding unknown object properties

Tags: javascript, regex, object

Some of the incoming objects I handle in my projects have unknown structures; properties I cannot depend on.  I decided to try to [build a function](http://codepen.io/fauxserious/pen/LGROBM) to help.

```
function getObjKeys(obj) {
  var keys = [];
  var regex = /"([^:,{}]+)":/g;
  var str = JSON.stringify(obj);
  var m;
  while (m = regex.exec(str)) {
    keys.push(m[1]);
  }
  return keys;
}
```

My question is, is there a better way of getting all the properties of an object with unknown structure? A mini-question also is; could the regex be improved? This is assuming the object is one level deep.  I figure, after getting the keys, one could iterate through them to find other objects and therefore other keys.

Comment: `Object.keys` should do the job

Comment: Provide a sample input with an **exact** matching output that you need

Comment: `Object.keys` support isn't as good as `JSON.stringify()`.  `Object.keys` would fail in IE8; I'm curious how far back a function to get object keys can go.

Comment: Do not use regexp to analyze objects in string form. Pain will ensue. If `Object.keys` is not available, then `for (var i in obj)` should work.

Comment: Sample is provided at the codepen link inside the post. http://codepen.io/fauxserious/pen/LGROBM

Comment: Seems like nothing could possibly beat for in, thanks @torazaburo